# phpmyadmin "Not Found" after install on Apache, Ubuntu

Tags: apache, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

Setting up a development environment with Ubuntu 14.04 running in VirtualBox, following this guide: http://klau.si/dev

After installing phpmyadmin, it seems I should be able to access it at `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` but apache returns a Not Found error. Did this guide leave out a configuration step somewhere? I have already tried restarting the apache service.

There is no phpmyadmin.conf file in apache2/sites-enabled or apache2/sites-available, is this required?

If so, where can I find these files?

using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost returns the same error. The default apache page at `http://localhost` works just fine.

the console in the browser shows nothing of value, simply Not Found.

I have also tried rerunning the install script with dpkg-reconfigure -plow phpmyadmin

Answer (score 150, accepted):

This issue was resolved thanks to this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP#Troubleshooting_Phpmyadmin_.26_mysql-workbench by adding

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

...to the /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file and restarting the service.

Comment: I got same problem using Ubuntu 19.04 and this worked. +1

Comment: same problem on ubuntu 18. another save my day moment!

Comment: Does not fix the issue for me. Page not found.

Comment: In case it helps anyone in the future: this has also worked for me on ubuntu 20.04. I did all the lamp install and then installed phpmyadmin with sudp apt-get install phpmyadmin. It all went well but http://localhost/phpmyadmin would give me 404 error. Not anymore after these steps.

Comment: It was helpful, you can edit the apache.conf by two ways..... "sudo edit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf"  or   "sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf"

Comment: Thanks , It works for me , after that I re started apache2 `sudo systemctl restart apache2`

Comment: Not working for me. Still getting 'page not found'.

Comment: This has also worked for me on ubuntu 20.04...this is after following all steps including `$ sudo a2enconf phpmyadmin`

Comment: Worked for me on ubuntu 22.04

Comment: I did this on Ubuntu 22.04 and it worked for me

Answer (score 87):

Try this

```
sudo ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf
sudo a2enconf phpmyadmin.conf
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Comment: Nope. Same "Page not found" error. This is getting predictable. Does Ubuntu ever work? Ever?

Comment: This helped me fine thanks to you!

Answer (score 60):

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -plow phpmyadmin
```

Select No when asked to reconfigure the database.  Then when asked to choose apache2, make sure to hit space while  [ ] apache2 is highlighted.  An asterisk should appear between the brackets.  Then hit Enter. Phpmyadmin should reconfigure and now http://localhost/phpmyadmin should work. for further detail https://www.howtoforge.com/installing-apache2-with-php5-and-mysql-support-on-ubuntu-13.04-lamp

Comment: This one is valid answer...also use tab to highlight an option like "ok" or "cancel"

Comment: Nope, keeping up with SO's apparent 100% track record of providing non-working answers wherever my Ubuntu install ins concerned, this leaves me with the same "Page not found" error it was supposed to solve.

Comment: Follow the steps as expained without leaving any point @JohnSmith

Answer (score 44):

The easiest way to do in ubuntu (I tested in ubuntu-20.04):

Step 1. Open the file:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Step 2: Add the following line at the end of file:

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

Step 3: Restart apache2:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

Answer (score 14):

Create a link in `/var/www` like this:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/
```

Note: since 14.04 you may want to use `/var/www/html/` instead of `/var/www/`

If that's not working for you, you need to include `PHPMyAdmin` inside apache configuration.

Open `apache.conf` using your favorite editor, mine is nano :)

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Then add the following line:

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

**For Ubuntu 15.04 and 16.04**

```
sudo ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf
sudo a2enconf phpmyadmin.conf
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Comment: what is username password default to login in phpmyadmin ?

Comment: NOPE! God, I'm just loving spending days and days on SO trying things to try and get my stock Ubuntu installation running, of which literally ZERO ever work. How does anyone ever use Ubuntu? Does it ever work at all? Literally NOBODY seems to know how to fix ANY problems with it at all.

Comment: @JohnSmith You ever find a solution to this? None of these worked for me either.

Answer (score 7):

> Finally I got the solution

```
sudo ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf
sudo a2enconf phpmyadmin
sudo service apache2 reload
```

> More about 
>   https://askubuntu.com/questions/55280/phpmyadmin-is-not-working-after-i-installed-it

Comment: Anyone checking my recent comment history will surely be shocked to know that NOPE this does not fix the problem at all. Page not found.

Comment: This fixed it for me, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Create a link in `/var/www/html` like this to fix the error:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/html
```

Comment: False, just like, apparently, every single other response to every single Ubuntu issue on SO... leaves me with the same Page Not Found error that every other "solution" does.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still running into issues with this- check that you're actually using apache!  I knocked my head against this for 20 minutes or so before I remembered...I use NginX on this server...=).  @john-smith, this one's for you buddy.

To get it working on nginx, all you should have to do is create a sim link and restart php:

`sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/html`

Note that for you, it may be `/var/www/` and not `/var/www/html`, depending on your dir structure.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf

sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/html/phpmyadmin

sudo service apache2 restart
```

Run above commands issue will be resolved.

Comment: Drumroll, please...... NOPE! The above commands do nothing to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command in terminal:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/html/
```

Comment: Does not do anything to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like sometime during the second half of 2018 many php packages such as php-mysql and phpmyadmin were removed or changed. I faced that same problem too. So you'll have to download it from another source or find out the new packages

Answer (score 0):

You will need to configure your apache2.conf to make phpMyAdmin works.

> sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Then add the following line to the end of the file.

> Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf

Then restart apache

> sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: False, does not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue where these fixes didn't work.

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 using hestiaCP with Nginx.

Today after adding

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

into both Apache and Nginx, Nginx failed to restart. It was having an issue with "proxy_buffers" value.

Yesterday I had to modify the Nginx config to add and increase these values so Magento 2.4 would run. Today I altered "proxy_buffers" again

```
proxy_buffers            3 64k;
proxy_buffer_size        128k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size  128k;
```

After the second alteration and the removal of "Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf" from both Apache and Nginx, Magento 2.4 and PHPMyAdmin are working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try Rashmi Jain's symlink answer. It seems like it would work. But if it doesn't work for you, perhaps try this.

I just created the file `/etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf' and added this line to it:

Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf

(rather than putting it into `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` as in Anonymous Man's answer)

Then:

```
sudo a2enconf phpmyadmin
sudo systemctl reload apache2
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after installing mysql, apache2, php and finally phpmyadmin after each other. In my case it was solved by restarting apache2 (no need to update any configuration file):

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Answer (score 0):

@John smith, I was facing the same issue of not being able to access phpmyadmin for 3 days, I found the solution.
-- Get xampp, check this tutorial https://youtu.be/VHfij95yOpo
-- Run this command before starting xampp app

`sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop`

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

That's it, it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

first go to the location of phpmyadmin via terminal then type this
code *php -S localhost:8001*

Comment: Although this is a way to get PHP to serve PHPMyAdmin, it isn't really the answer to the question, since the question is about using it with Apache. It also doesn't really explain what that does. It should also include supporting information.

Answer (score -1):

First check `PhpMyAdmin` is install or not. If it is installed then search `PhpMyadmin` folder. After search cut and paste that folder in location `Computer->var->www->html->paste folder`. Open browser and type `localhost/phpMyAdmin` and login using username and password.

Answer (score -1):

**If you are having this problem in 2019**, go to your *`000-default.conf`* file, by typing this `subl /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` (in your terminal to open the file in sublime editor)

When the file loads, locate "**The ServerName directive sets the request scheme**" and place this "**Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf**" on top .

Then restart your apache with the command...`service apache2 restart` That will certainly fix the issue. Hope it helps!

Comment: It certainly did nothing to fix the issue. Page not found.